# get partial data from BLOB as hex

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a long binary written to MySQL as long BLOB.
When I read the BLOB back from the DB by my PHP app, I would like to take the first 12 bytes only as hex.
I successfully converted the BLOB to hex by using bin2hex(BLOB) but don't know how to ignore the data over the first 12 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something this?

```sql
SELECT HEX(LEFT(data, 12)) partial
  FROM table1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a05d6/4)** demo

[The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html)

> BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings).

Therefore you can grab first 12 bytes with `LEFT()` and then convert them with `HEX()`

---

I believe in Codeigniter you can do something like this

```php
$result = $this->db
               ->select('HEX(LEFT(data, 12)) AS partial', FALSE)
               ->from('table1')
               ->get();
```

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter to SELECT. I will look to see how this can be done there